# Stop music after scene ends

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I got this animation homework.
 I wanted to put a couple of bgm in it. 
I placed the first one, and it refuses to stop when the scene ends. 
I place the music in a individual frameline but it doesn't stop when frames end. 
So, I insert a keyframe behind it, and put this codes :

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer.*;
soundmixer.stopAll();
```

In which I got the errors :
definition of flash.media.SoundMixer could not be found (twice), for line 1 
 access of undefined property soundmixer, at line 2.  
I also tried stopAllsounds; , which is also undefined (even after I import flash.media)

(ps: there is hardly any codes inside this animation - it only has the codes for the replay button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

if(SoundMixer.areSoundsInaccessible() == false) {
  SoundMixer.stopAll();
} else {
  trace("There are inaccessible sounds.");
}
```

But you may have to check where you are loading the sound files from, and fix the security issues (cf., [Adobe SoundMixer docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html)).

---

The problem was that you were importing SoundMixer incorrectly (with the ".*" on the end), and you were using it as if it was an instance, rather than a static class.

Comment: erm... ...  then how do i stop ONLY that sound... cause it interfered with my other sounds...

Comment: Yes, it is designed to stop all sounds, as the method name suggests.  To stop one sound, you should post the code for loading the sound.  But I think it may be enough to review the Adobe docs on using that code.

Comment: wull, yull haf ta read!  Here's the [Adobe docs for SoundChannel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#stop%28%29), which I use to control audio, and here are [some tuts on how to use it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d21.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d10).